# Sum and product of interpolation polynomials

Tags: numerical-methods, interpolation

Let $w_1,w_2$ be Lagrange's interpolating polynomials of functions $f_1,f_2$ using the same nodes.

1. Prove that polynomial $w(x)=w_1(x)+w_2(x)$ is Lagrange's interpolating polynomial of function $f(x)=f_1(x)+f_2(x)$
2. Check if the product of these polynomial has analogical property.

So I have noticed that $l_i=\prod_{j=0,\ j\neq i}^n \frac{x-x_j}{x_i-x_j}$ would be the same for poth polynomials, as it depends only on the nodes.
$$
w(x)=w_1(x)+w_2(x)=\sum_{i=0}^n f_{1_i} l_i+\sum_{i=0}^n f_{2_i} l_i=\sum_{i=0}^n (f_{1_i}+f_{2_i}) l_i=\sum_{i=0}^n f_i l_i
$$
And the last term is just interpolating polynomial of $f(x)=f_1(x)+f_2(x)$, so that concludes the proof.

For 2nd part of the task I'm not sure, but I think that there is no such property, and I just need a counterexample?

Please chceck the validity of proof of the 1st part and answer my question for the 2nd part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your response for the first question is correct.

Regarding question 2., the interesting point is that indeed, the product $w_1w_2$ interpolates the function $f_1f_2$. But this is not **the** Lagrange's interpolating polynomial as it hasn't the right degree.

For example, $w_1(x)=x$ interpolates a (any) function $f_1$ with $f_1(-1)=-1$ and $f_1(1)=1$. In the same manner, $w_2(x)=-x$ interpolates a (any) function $f_2$ with $f_1(-1)=1$ and $f_1(1)=-1$.

The polynomial $w(x) = -x^2 = w_1(x) w_2(x)$ interpolates $f_1f_2$ at $-1$ and $1$. However $w$ **is not** the Lagrange interpolating polynomial $\mathcal L(x)$ such that $w(-1)=w(1)=-1$. $\mathcal L(x)$ is in fact the constant function equals to $-1$.